# funcion no se ejecuta en un clone javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, clone

pues bien tengo unas funciones que hacen que un input muestre sugerencias de nombres a medida que se escribe y esas sugerencias las trae de una base de datos y otra función que completa los datos restantes como son nit y profesión todo funciona pero al hacer un clone del contenedor de los inputs la función de crear sugerencias no se ejecuta cual puede ser mi error dejo los códigos

**traer.php**

este lo que hace es consultar los nombres o apellidos escritos en el input i traer los datos faltantes

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $names = $_POST['names'];
    $valores = array();
    $valores['existe'] = "0";
    $workers = array();

    //CONSULTAR
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios`
    WHERE first_name COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$names%' 
    OR second_name COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$names%'
    OR first_surname COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$names%'
    OR second_surname COLLATE UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$names%'
    OR CONCAT(first_name,' ',second_name,' ',first_surname,' ',second_surname) COLLATE 
    UTF8_SPANISH_CI LIKE '%$names%'");

while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
    $valores['existe'] = "1";
    $valores['nombres'] = $consulta['first_name']." 
    ".$consulta['second_name']."".$consulta['first_surname']." ".$consulta['second_surname'];
    $valores['documento'] = $consulta['n_documento'];
    $valores['cargo'] = $consulta['cargo_e'];
}
}sleep(1);$valores = json_encode($valores);echo $valores;?>
```

**luego esta el workers.php**

```
$valores = array();
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `status` = 'activo'");
while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
    $valores = $consulta['first_name'] . " " . $consulta['second_name'] . " " . $consulta['first_surname'] . " " . $consulta['second_surname'].",";
    echo $valores;
}
```

**y este es el main.js**

en este esta la función para generar las sugerencias, el clone del contenedor, la función para consultar los usuarios y crear un array con sus nombres y por ultimo la función de autocompletar

```
"use strict";

let autocomplete = (inp, arr) => {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  let currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    let a, //OUTER html: variable for listed content with html-content
      b, // INNER html: filled with array-Data and html
      i, //Counter
      val = this.value;

    /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
    closeAllLists();

    if (!val) {
      return false;
    }

    currentFocus = -1;

    /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
    a = document.createElement("DIV");

    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items list-group text-left");

    /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
        b = document.createElement("DIV");
        b.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item list-group-item-action");
        /*make the matching letters bold:*/
        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
        /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
        /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
        b.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
        });
        a.appendChild(b);
      }
    }
  });

  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  let addActive = (x) => {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = x.length - 1;
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("active");
  }

  let removeActive = (x) => {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }

  let closeAllLists = (elmnt) => {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });

};


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// HASTA AQUI ES LO QUE GENERA LAS SUGERENCIAS
// ------------------------------------------------------------


// CLONAR LOS CAMPOS INICIO
var padre = document.getElementById('padreContenedor');
var btn_copy = document.getElementById('btnCopiar');
btn_copy.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const hijo = document.getElementById('hijoContenedor')
    const copia = hijo.cloneNode(true)
    copia.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(e => e.value = "");
      padre.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copia)
}
// CLONAR LOS CAMPOS FIN

// CONSULTAR A BD LOS NOMBRES DE LOS TRABAJADORES
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $.post("workers.php",function(data){
    let mydata = data
    let workers = mydata.split(',')
    // console.log(workers)
    $('.busqueda').on('focus',()=>{
      let myinput = $('#busqueda:focus')[0]
      autocomplete(myinput, workers);
    })
  })
})
// CONSULTAR A BD LOS NOMBRES DE LOS TRABAJADORES FIN

// AUTOCOMPLETAR LOS CAMPOS INICIO
$('.busqueda').on('focus', (e) => {
  $(this).on('keyup change blur', ()=>{
    let names = $('.busqueda:focus').val();
    // console.log(names)
    var parametros = {
      "buscar": "1",
      "names": names
    };
    $.ajax({
      data: parametros,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'traer.php',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(valores) {
        if (valores.existe == "1" && names != "") { //Aqui usamos la variable que NO use en el vídeo
          // $("#nombre").val(valores.nombre);
          $('#busqueda:focus').parent().parent().children('.col-md-4').children('#ident').val(valores.documento);
          $('#busqueda:focus').parent().parent().children('.col-md-4').children("#cargo").val(valores.cargo);
        } else {
          $('#busqueda:focus').parent().parent().children('.col-md-4').children('#ident').val('');
          $('#busqueda:focus').parent().parent().children('.col-md-4').children("#cargo").val('');
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
// AUTOCOMPLETAR LOS CAMPOS FIN
```

**Y EL HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Ajax</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5>Traer Datos</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="padreContenedor">
            <div class="row g-3 mb-3" id="hijoContenedor">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="busqueda" class="busqueda form-control" placeholder="Nombres">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="ident" class="form-control ident" placeholder="N° de Identidad">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" id="cargo" class="form-control cargo" placeholder="Cargo / Rol">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="btnCopiar">Copiar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

he probado acceder a el input con clase e id busqueda de muchas maneras pero no estoy seguro si es porque este no se carga cuando carga el documento

Comment: ¿Viste si la consola mostraba errores? Por cierto, los scripts debes importarlos _en la última línea antes de cerrar el `body`_. Te recomiendo mover el script de jquery a esa zona también (antes de los demás scripts).

Comment: la verdad es que como no se ejecuta no lo iba a mostrar pero ya se soluciono de igual manera gracias

Answer (score 1):

bueno después de analizarlo llegue a la conclusión de que era mejor volver a ejecutar la misma función dentro del evento del clone para así "actualizar el numero de inputs con clase .busqueda" existentes y funciono dejo lo modificado por si alguien necesita se que probablemente no es la mejor forma de hacerlo pero pues es como de momento lo logre solucionar

```
// CONSULTAR A BD LOS NOMBRES DE LOS TRABAJADORES
function quedata(){
  $.post("workers.php",function(data){
    let mydata = data
    let workers = mydata.split(',')
    // console.log(workers)
    $(document).find($('.busqueda')).on('focus',()=>{
      let myinput = $('#busqueda:focus')[0]
      autocomplete(myinput, workers);
    })
  })
}
// CONSULTAR A BD LOS NOMBRES DE LOS TRABAJADORES FIN

// CLONAR LOS CAMPOS INICIO
var padre = document.getElementById('padreContenedor');
var btn_copy = document.getElementById('btnCopiar');
btn_copy.onclick = function copyPaste(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const hijo = document.getElementById('hijoContenedor')
    const copia = hijo.cloneNode(true)
    copia.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(e => e.value = "")
    padre.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', copia)
    quedata()
}
// CLONAR LOS CAMPOS FIN
```